# Webpack failed to load resource. bundle.js 404

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, webpack

A little background. I've been following this tutorial: https://itnext.io/a-template-for-creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-flask-npm-webpack-and-reactjs-be2294b111bd and have been troubleshooting the issue in the title for a while now.

The code compiles and the server runs however there is a 404 error looking for bundle.js.

My folder structure is:

```
.
├── web-app
    ├── configurations.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── README.md
    ├── run.py
    └── templates
        ├── hello
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── views.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── public
        │   ├── css
        │   ├── fonts
        │   ├── images
        │   └── js
        └── static
            ├── index.html
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── js
               ├── components
               ├── index.jsx
               └── routes.js
```

My webpack.config.js is:

```
var path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const config = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output:{
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.jsx?/,
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  exclude: /node_modules/,
                  query: {
                      presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                  }
              },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules'
            }]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Lastly, my index.js is:

```
<!— index.html —>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css">
    <title>Creating a Full-Stack Python Application with Flask, NPM, React.js and Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" />
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I run "npm run watch" and receive a 404 error for its inability to find bundle.js. The url path it looks for is https://www.mywebsitehere.com/public/bundle.js.

I believe I've set flask to look for the correct paths in my web-app/templates/**init**.py file as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder = './public',
            template_folder="./static")

from templates.hello.views import hello_blueprint
# register the blueprints
app.register_blueprint(hello_blueprint)
```

I know this is a lot of code, but after a good amount of research and troubleshooting, I remain at square one. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index.html, the `script`'s `src` points to `public/bundle.js`, but your webpack config's output is to `(dir containing webpack config)/dist/bundle.js`. Your folder structure doesn't show where the webpack config is, but you want to make sure the config's output and the html `script`'s `src` attribute are pointing to the same path.

Comment: So the webpack.config.js is in the same directory as the index.html file in ~/web-app/templates/static. I've changed the src in index.html to dist/bundle.js and I still get the same error. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: It sounds like your webpack config and index.html are pointing to the same file location now, so it could be a routing issue in your Flask app.

Comment: I think you are right. I will look into the routing separately. I've marked your answer as correct and appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, I hope you find the solution, sorry I couldn't be more help with Flask!